# Performing cluster analysis when separate clusters and point layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, vector, clustering

I have a garbage patch layer (cluster) and a plastic accumulation points (point). The number of points are less compared to the spread of clusters.  there are many extra clusters. I want to identify the specific cluster each point belongs to. finally I want to make this result in to an output.

Is there anyway to do this using ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: You had a tag for ArcGIS Pro so I've focused your question on that.  If you wish to ask about doing the same thing using another GIS software then please do so in a separate question, and be sure to describe not just what you want to do but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I tried to use mapping clusters in spatial statistics tools of Arcgis desktop. But it doesn't allow me to input two layers. it uses a one layer to process. Thank you